# make python sort / compare the same way as GNU sort

Tags: python, bash, shell, sorting

It seems after some first tests, that Python is using the same sorting order as Linux sort (gnu sort) with the C sorting order (if the locale is set to "C").

However I'd like to be able to write  Python code that is sorting and comparing the same way as gnu sort depending on the locale.

Small example code to illustrate the issue:

```
import os 
import subprocess

words = [
    "Abd",
    "éfg",
    "aBd",
    "aBd",
    "zzz",
    "ZZZ",
    "efg",
    "abd",
    "fff",
    ]

with open("tosort", "w") as fout:
    for word in words:
        fout.write(word + "\n")

os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "en_US.UTF-8" 
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "tosort"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sort_en_utf = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split()

os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "C" 
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "tosort"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
sort_c = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split()

os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
sort_py = sorted(words)

for row in zip(sort_en_utf, sort_c, sort_py):
    print(" ".join(row))
```

If above code is run I get following output:

```
abd Abd Abd
aBd ZZZ ZZZ
aBd aBd aBd
Abd aBd aBd
efg abd abd
éfg efg efg
fff fff fff
zzz zzz zzz
ZZZ éfg éfg
```

column 1 is the sorting / comparing order that I'd like to have in my python code if the locale is "en_US.UTF-8" column 2 and 3 show, that python sorts the same way as linux' sort if the locale is set to "C".

So I'd also like, to know whether there is a way to have:

`"éfg" < "fff"` yield True. I don't insist on a compare operator I can also call a function.
but the ordering result should be considering  the current locale.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/674039

Comment: will look at natsort. will check especially whether this libary respects the locale.
and whether it would also sort letters like "ß" (should be sorted like "ss")

Comment: Just checked natsort. it is interesting but doing something different. it will for example order numbers within strings differently e.g. `"a2" < "a10"`, so it wouldn't behave identical to a sort without options but a locale with UTF

Comment: the doc of natsort mentions PyICU https://pypi.org/project/PyICU/ will look at this one now

Comment: If you need this to be foolproof, the best way might be actually calling bash sort from python :)

Comment: Thanks wim.

Your suggestion to look at the other article made me follow a series of several links, which led me in the end to howto/sorting.html, where I should have looked in the first place.

Comment: @wim, well this is what I'm doing at the moment (calling subprocess, sort) , but I don't really like it that much, though the sort command is fast and falls back to merge sort if the files are really huge, so no danger of consuming all RAM.

In fact I had one issue, where I was sorting a list the command line sort and then I was processing the result with a python script.
The fact, that both did not agree on the same ordering cost me quite some debugging time

Comment: my bad. will change the title.
And you're right bash sort was not really good wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm somehow I overlooked this:

The sorting doc of python https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/sorting.html mentions in the last section "Odds and Ends" the function locale.strxfrm() (see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/locale.html#locale.strxfrm ) as key function for sorting and locale.strcoll() as a comparison function.

So following modified code is almost OK, except that the comparison function does not return directly true / false, but this is OK in my context

```
import subprocess

words = [
    "Abd",
    "éfg",
    "aBd",
    "aBd",
    "zzz",
    "ZZZ",
    "efg",
    "abd",
    "fff",
    "sra",
    "ssa",
    "ssb",
    "stb",
    "ßaa",
    ]

val1 = "ßaa"
val2 = "ssb"

with open("tosort", "w") as fout:
    for word in words:
        fout.write(word + "\n")

os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "tosort"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sort_en_utf = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split()

os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "C"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sort", "tosort"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sort_c = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")
sort_py1 = sorted(words, key=locale.strxfrm)
print("%r < %r = %s , but locale.strcoll(%r, %r) = %s for %s"
      % (val1, val2, val1 < val2, val1, val2,
         locale.strcoll(val1, val2), locale.getlocale())
      )

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "C")
sort_py2 = sorted(words, key=locale.strxfrm)
print("%r < %r = %s , but locale.strcoll(%r, %r) = %s for %s"
      % (val1, val2, val1 < val2, val1, val2,
         locale.strcoll(val1, val2), locale.getlocale())
      )

for row in zip(sort_en_utf, sort_py1, sort_c, sort_py2):
    print(" ".join(row))
```

The output would be

```
'ßaa' < 'ssb' = False , but locale.strcoll('ßaa', 'ssb') = -1 for ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
'ßaa' < 'ssb' = False , but locale.strcoll('ßaa', 'ssb') = 1 for (None, None)
abd abd Abd Abd
aBd aBd ZZZ ZZZ
aBd aBd aBd aBd
Abd Abd aBd aBd
efg efg abd abd
éfg éfg efg efg
fff fff fff fff
sra sra sra sra
ssa ssa ssa ssa
ßaa ßaa ssb ssb
ssb ssb stb stb
stb stb zzz zzz
zzz zzz ßaa ßaa
ZZZ ZZZ éfg éfg
```

Comment: now looking for the best way to set the locale to the calling shell's locale.

Didn't come up with anything better than `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, os.environ.get("LC_ALL", os.environ.get("LANG", "C")))`

Comment: `key=lambda v: locale.strxfrm(v)` can be simplified to `key=locale.strxfrm`

Comment: @boOk. yes true. will change

Comment: I thought comparison functions were deprecated in favor of key functions?

Comment: @Mark Ransom can you elaborate?  I do use key functions

Comment: The text talks about a comparison function, so that's what I based my comment on.  Didn't notice that the code is at odds with the text.